# adding a class attrib to html element based on certain condition javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul element in my html..

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu"> /<ul>
```

which can have `<li>` elements of two kinds..

a) simple..

```
<li>
                <a href="/Campaign/CreateCampaignUrl">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Campaign Url</span>
                    <small class="label pull-right bg-green">new</small>
                </a>
            </li>
```

b) complex..

```
<li class="treeview">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                    <span>Classify Events</span>
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Standard Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Campaign/ClassifyCampaignProperties"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Campaign Properties</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

I wish to add class attribute with value 'active' to a specific `<li>` element via javascript

In my javascript I have a variable my_url.

if my_url matches a href of simple `<li>` say.. "/Campaign/CreateCampaignUrl" then I want the `<li>` to look as below, the li element has class="active"..

```
<li class="active">
                    <a href="/Campaign/CreateCampaignUrl">
                        <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Campaign Url</span>
                        <small class="label pull-right bg-green">new</small>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

else if complex `<li>` matches..

```
<li class="treeview active">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                        <span>Classify Events</span>
                        <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Standard Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Campaign/ClassifyCampaignProperties"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Campaign Properties</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

In this case, active value attaches to class in two places..

a) the li element which has the url which matches to my_url.. in above example "/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent".

b) the main li element which had class="treeview" has now class="treeview active"

All help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to post your JavaScript

Comment: I have not been able to figure out what js will solve this problem.. currently I just have var my_url ="url string to match"

Comment: An attempt should be made by you to solve your problem, otherwise it's an incomplete question.

Comment: Exactly how is "simple" and "complex" defined here? Do complex elements simply have the `treeview` class, or is it there specific structure?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek complex elements  have treeview class which in turm have a ul element with 'treeview-menu class' which in turn has li elements which has the 'a' element with href

Comment: @AyexeM actually, the actual problem is quite big..the value for my_url comes from a complex javascript logic which i was able to do but got stuck at the html part, I'm primarily a serverside coder and am challenged when writing client side code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't initially mention you are using jQuery I am going to give you a vanilla javascript answer:

What you want to do is select all links within the menu and run through them one-by-one. For each link you want to traverse upwards through the parentNodes until it matches the menu element and add the active class to any elements that have `tagName` of `"LI"`.

```
var my_url = '/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent';

var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-menu')[0];
var links = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');

function highlight(linkEl) {
  var el = linkEl;

  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName === 'LI') el.className += ' active';
  } while (el !== menu);
}

var i, linkEl;

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
  linkEl = links[i];

  if (linkEl.getAttribute('href') === my_url) {
    highlight(linkEl);
    // break here to stop at first match
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96y4nzvm/4/

This will highlight the line items of all matching links, but if you want to limit it to the first match you can throw a break inside the if in the bottom for-loop.

EDIT:
Since you have added jQuery to your list of tags here is my jQuery solution as well (same concept):

```
var my_url = '/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent';

var $menus = $('.sidebar-menu');

$menus.each(function (i) {
  var $menu = $menus.eq(i);
  var $links = $menu.find('a[href="' + my_url +'"]');

  $links.each(function (i) {
    var $link = $links.eq(i);
    $link.parentsUntil($menu ,'li').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

jQuery fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96y4nzvm/7/

The jQuery solution has the added benefit of being able to work across multiple menus (for instance, one that shows up for desktop width, and another that shows up for mobile width).

Comment: They are OK using jQuery, they added it as a tag in the edit. Also this only seems to handle the simple case and not the complex one.

Comment: It handles both. It keeps traversing upwards to highlight all ancestors of type "LI" (until it reaches the parent menu). I will add my jQuery solution since they added that tag.

Comment: They don't want to do it for every `li` element that's an ancestor.

Comment: Sure they do, look at the markup. It stops when it reaches the menu though.

Comment: No they do not. And they specifically said this: *"In this case, active value attaches to class in **two places**.."*.

Comment: There are only two ancestor LI tags between the matched complex link and the menu it is in. It's a shortcut I was able to boil out of the provided specs.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all li elements and search for a child A element with the matching href, assuming jQuery :

```
var my_url = '/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent';

$('.sidebar-menu>li').each(function(){
  var add_active = false;
  $(this).find('a').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href') == my_url){
        if (!add_active) {
        add_active = true;
      }
    }
  });
  if (add_active) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

EDIT : updated code

Comment: Yeah, that code shouldn't work at all, `Array.prototype.forEach()` is plain JavaScript/DOM, and you're chaining that to a jQuery collection/object. You, probably, meant to use jQuery's `each ()` method @

Comment: @Arnab Your question is a little unclear, you might want to edit it. I've modified my example code with what I believe your issue is.

Comment: the complex case does not work.. jsfiddle.net/8k0v9eyL/4 only the li with treeview class which has element under it which has the reqd url should become active .. not all

Comment: Your JSfilddle is not for my answer, it is for @Spencer Wieczorek

Comment: sorry for that.. plz look at the complex section ur logic checks for url in href in simple scenarios and if it does not find the same adds active to treeview  of all complex li elements.. what I need is it must look for the ahref which has the my_url value and then look for its parent li and then chk if that in turn has a parent li with treeview class.. add active class to it

Comment: y.. u r right as far as connecting to matching href in simple as well as complex scenarios, but in complex scenarios.. u add active in two places.. so u will first have to find whether the case is complex and if so add active to parent li as stated in my prev comment..

Comment: I've updated my answer, it is working now. http://jsfiddle.net/bwf8d8f0/
The issue was that I was only checking the first a tag for the href, this version loops through all first level li tags, and loops through all its a decendants looking for the href.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to select the right elements with a selector and add the `active` class:

```
// Simple
$("ul.sidebar-menu > li").find("a[href='/Campaign/CreateCampaignUrl']")
        .parent("li").addClass("active");
// Complex
var $aSelector = $("ul.sidebar-menu > li.treeview > ul.treeview-menu > li")
        .find("a[href='/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent']");

$aSelector.parent("li").addClass("active");
$aSelector.closest("li.treeview").addClass("active");
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8k0v9eyL/6/)

The simple selector finds the `a` tag with the href `/Campaign/CreateCampaignUrl`, then goes to the parent `li` and applies the `active` class.

The complex selector we first find `a` element that have a `/ClassificationUI/ClassifyStandardEvent` under `.treeview-menu`. We then add the active class to the direct parent `li`, and also `active` to the `li` ancestor that has a `treeview` class.

Comment: the simple case works the complex does not.. https://jsfiddle.net/8k0v9eyL/4/   only the li with treeview class which has element under it which has the reqd url should become active .. not all

Comment: @Arnab Oh sorry I miss read your `a)` part (thought you where mentioning the simple case), one second.

Comment: so, the code must figure out if the href is in li which has  a parent li element with treeview class and if so add active to class attrib

Comment: @Arnab Sorry for the misunderstanding, I've updated my question.

Comment: also, u will need to use .sidebar before checking for the reqd a href as I might have in other sections of page other li elements which have  same a href

Comment: Sure, you can simply state that in the selector by adding `ul.sidebar-menu ...`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: when I add a var my_url and add the url value there, it does not work https://jsfiddle.net/8k0v9eyL/7/  what am i doing wrong??

Comment: @Arnab You are using the actual string value `my_url` rather than the variable, you will want to concatenate it to the string (`"a[href='"+my_url+"']"`). When concatenating be careful of the double quotes as they are used for the string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both simple & complex scenarios (even nested).

```js
//var my_url = '/Campaign/CreateCampaignUrl';
var my_url = '/Campaign/ClassifyCampaignProperties';
var $menu = $('.sidebar-menu');
var addActiveClass = function(index, elem) {
  var activeClass = 'active';
  var $link = $(elem);
  var linkSrc = $link.attr('href');
  var $parent = $link.parent();
  var $treeViewParent = $link.closest('.treeview');
  if (linkSrc && linkSrc.indexOf(my_url) !== -1) {
    $parent.addClass(activeClass);
    if ($treeViewParent.length) {
        $treeViewParent.addClass(activeClass);
    }
  }
};

// Simple & Complex
$.each($menu.find('a'), addActiveClass);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7pcrwa4j/)

[Nested Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7pcrwa4j/1/)